# Changing inner values in a list of items

Tags: javascript, html

Let say I have a HTML code:

```
<li>
    <button class="add">+</button>
    <span class="amount">0</span>
    <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
<li>
    <button class="add">+</button>
    <span class="amount">0</span>
    <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
and so on...
```

and JS:

```
  function addAmount(el) {
    let amount = document.querySelector(".amount");
    let addAmount = parseInt(amount.innerHTML);
    if (el.classList.contains("add")) {
      addAmount = addAmount + 1;
      amount.innerHTML = addAmount;
    }
    return addAmount;
  }

    document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  addAmount(e.target);
});
```

This code works only for first li element. I would like to know how I can obtain a code in which every button from each li element is responsible for only one element (one button adds value for one li element).

Comment: `document.querySelector(".amount")` returns the first element. If you use `document.querySelectorAll(".amount")` instead, you can use `document.querySelectorAll(".amount")[0]` to get the first, `[1]` to the the 2nd, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I would try this. I had no idea I can write code such as document.querySelectorAll(".amount")[0] with [0] on end.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.querySelector` at all. You just want to get the element before or after `e.target`. Use `el.previousElementSibling` or `el.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".amount")` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Example).

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much it works! Instead of `document.querySelector` I used `el.nextElementSibling` and all buttons from the list works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be searching the document at all. You can use `document.querySelectorAll(".amount")` to get a list of all the `amount` fields, but you need to figure out which index to use.

Instead, you can use `previousElementSibling` or `nextElementSibling` to get the element before or after the button you clicked on.

```js
function addAmount(el) {
  let amountElement, adjustAmount
  if (el.classList.contains("add")) {
    adjustAmount = 1;
    amountElement = el.nextElementSibling;
  } else {
    adjustAmount = -1;
    amountElement = el.previousElementSibling;
  }
  amountElement.innerText = parseInt(amountElement.innerText) + adjustAmount;
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  addAmount(e.target);
});
```

```html
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
<li>
  <button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="amount">0</span>
  <button class="substract">-</button>
</li>
```